# Insert CSS Resource into Classic Domino Web Development page using SSL

Tags: css, ssl, lotus-notes, lotus-domino

I'm running into issues with css resources within a classical Domino Web Application when I test it with https://.

I've inserted these css resources as normal resources into the HTML Head Content of the page in question.

I can't seem to find any setting which tells domino to link the css using the https:// protocol instead of http.

Does anybody have an idea? Is there a workaround?

> Mixed Content: The page at
>   'https://www.magermandemo2.ch/Development/webres/webres1_0/Webres_(1_0)_Dev.nsf/LocationTeamSelect'
>   was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script
>   'http://www.magermandemo2.ch/Development/webres/webres1_0/Webres_(1_0)_Dev.nsf/app.js!OpenJavaScriptLibrary'.
>   This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

Comment: Please show the Code you used in HTML Head to link the css. It seams that you use an abolute url instead of a relative one. I would expect something like: `"/" + @WebDbName + "/app.js!OpenJavaScriptLibrary`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK: I will try to answer this even though the code is missing. Normally you don't even need to care about "how" your database is opened as long as you use relative URLs:

Don't use the "default" way to embedd the reosurce, but use formula in the HTML-Head-Content for the form.
Use a formula like this to compute your header:

```
_url := "/" + @WebDbName + "/app.js!OpenJavaScriptLibrary"
"<script src='" + _url + "'></script>"
```

Like this it absolutely does not matter, if you call the site with "http" or "https".

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Torsten. I was using the 'standard' way of including the css resources.

Comment: just a small correction: you need to assign with := and not =. Spent quite some time trying to work that one out :-)

Comment: Fixed the typo. Sorry for that!